# Reading unique elements from file in c#

Tags: c#

I have a file as

```
outlook temperature Humidity  Windy  PlayTennis

sunny      hot        high     false   N

sunny      hot        high     true    N

overcast   hot        high     false   P

rain       mild       high     false   P

rain       cool       normal   false   P
```

I want to read only unique elements from each column.

My ouput should be:

```
 elements: occurence         
sunny : 2
overcast :1 
rain : 2
hot: 3
cold : ans so on
mild
high
normal
true
false
N
P
```

I want to store this in dictionary, as key value pair 
key would be my row element. value will be its column element.
Please help.

Comment: What is the separator in the file? What is the dictionary, a `Dictionary<string,string>`? What is a row elenment, do you mean the line?

Comment: Space is the seperator..

Comment: Dictionary <string,string>

Comment: I read contents from the file..
i am able to get only column value, but they are not unique.

Comment: var text1 = File.ReadAllLines(file);
                    File.WriteAllLines(file,text1.Skip(1).ToArray());
                    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (string s in text1)
                    {
                        str.Append(s);

                        str.AppendLine();
                    }
                    textBox1.Text = str.ToString();
i am firstly trying to store only unique value of column in a textbox..but ia m able to all the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, so first you have to load the file content:

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
```

Now, you should remove empty lines and replace multiple spaces with a single space character. Regex and Linq come in handy here.

```
string[] nonEmptyLines = allLines.Where(s => s.Trim(' ') != "")
                .Select(s => Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+", " ")).ToArray();
```

Let's read columns headers now:

```
string[] columnHeaders = null;
if (nonEmptyLines.Length > 0)
    columnHeaders = nonEmptyLines[0].Split();
else
    return;
```

Check how many columns there are:

```
int columnsCount = columnHeaders.Length;
```

Skip the first line that contains column headers and split the values to string array with the following Linq syntax.

```
var linesValues = nonEmptyLines.Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split());
```

Finally, it's time to write the unique results to the Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> columnValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (int i = 0; i < columnsCount; i++)
{
    foreach (string[] values in linesValues)
    {
        if (!columnValues.ContainsKey(values[i]))
        {
            columnValues.Add(values[i], columnHeaders[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

That's all. I've tested it on your example and it worked for me.

Comment: I also want to find the occurence of each thing.. i.e sunny should be 2..overcast should be 1..hot should be 3..
I tried but i am getting occurence of all letters.
can u please help

Answer (score 0):

Just make a HashSet for each column and store the values under it in the corresponding HashSet. Print all of the elements from each HashSet when you finished adding them all to the HashSet.

```
var text1 = File.ReadAllLines(file);
HashSet<string>[] columns = new HashSet<string>[text1[0].Split(" \t".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length];

for(int i=0; i<columns.Length; i++)
{
    columns[i] = new HashSet<string>();
}

foreach (string row in text1.Skip(1))
{
    string[] words = row.Split(" \t".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (words.Length == columns.Length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            columns[i].Add(words[i]);
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < columns.Length; i++)
{
    foreach (string value in columns[i])
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I also want to find the occurence of each thing.. i.e sunny should be 2..overcast should be 1..hot should be 3.. I tried but i am getting occurence of all letters. can u please help